# IOException in catch while loading a txt file in a Java FX application

Tags: java, exception, javafx, io

After running this code I always get `Exception happened while loading 'Sokoban.txt'` printed which means that an `IOException` is always catched. 
I'm trying to convert a Java Project into a Java FX application and don't understand why the loading of the txt file doesn't work here anymore.
I would be grateful any hints or help

```
package sokobangame;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sokobangame extends Application {

private final static int X = 0;
private final static int Y = 1;

private final static char WALL = '#';
private final static char PLAYER = '@';
private final static char BOX = '$';
private final static char GOAL = '.';
private final static char PLAYER_ON_GOAL = '+';
private final static char BOX_ON_GOAL = '*';
private final static char FREE = ' ';

private final static int[] UP = {0, -1};
private final static int[] DOWN = {0, 1};
private final static int[] LEFT = {-1, 0};
private final static int[] RIGHT = {1, 0};

private static char[][] room;
private static int freeBox;
private static int emptyGoal;

private static int[] size = {-1, 0};
private static int[] player;
public static String file = "sokoban.txt";

/**
 * Loads the level from the "file" and validate it
 *
 * @param file path to the file
 * @return false iff an error occurs or the level is invalid, true otherwise
 */
private static boolean loadLevel(String file) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    try {
        bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file));
        bufferedReader.mark(100 * 100);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println("line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null");

            size[Y]++;
            if (size[X] > -1 && size[X] != line.length()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                size[X] = line.length();
            }
        }

        bufferedReader.reset();
        room = new char[size[Y]][];

        int i = 0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            room[i] = new char[line.length()];
            for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
                room[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
            }
            i++;
            // oder room[i++] = line.toCharArray();
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception happened while loading 'Sokoban.txt'");
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < room[i].length; j++) {
            switch (room[i][j]) {
                case FREE:
                case BOX_ON_GOAL:
                case WALL:
                    break;
                case PLAYER_ON_GOAL:
                    emptyGoal++;
                case PLAYER:
                    if (player != null) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        player = new int[]{j, i};
                    }
                    break;
                case BOX:
                    freeBox++;
                    break;
                case GOAL:
                    emptyGoal++;
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return !(player == null || emptyGoal != freeBox);
}

/**
 * Prints the level to the output stream
 */
private static void printLevel() {
    for (char[] row : room) {
        System.out.println(row);
    }
}

/**
 * Function for vector addition
 *
 * @param first first vector
 * @param second second vector
 * @return new vector = first + second
 */
private static int[] add(int[] first, int[] second) {
    return new int[]{first[X] + second[X], first[Y] + second[Y]};
}

/**
 * Game logic for Sokoban
 *
 * @return true iff the level was solved, otherwise false
 */
private static boolean game() {
    // create new Scanner that reads from console
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // flag if we quit the program
    boolean run = true;
    int[] direction;
    do {
        printLevel();
        System.out.println("Do you want to go up, down, left, right or exit the program?");

        // check which command was chosen and execute it
        switch (input.next()) {
            case "w":
            case "up":
                direction = UP;
                break;
            case "s":
            case "down":
                direction = DOWN;
                break;
            case "a":
            case "left":
                direction = LEFT;
                break;
            case "d":
            case "right":
                direction = RIGHT;
                break;
            case "exit":
                run = false;
                continue;
            default: // if the user input is not one of our commands print help
                System.out.println("Command unknown! Please type up, down, left or right to move or exit to quit this program");
                continue;
        }

        if (!move(direction)) {
            System.out.println("You can not go there!");
        }
    } while (run && emptyGoal != 0 && freeBox != 0);
    return run;
}

/**
 * Makes a move
 *
 * @param direction as a vector
 * @return true iff it was successful, otherwise false
 */
private static boolean move(int[] direction) {
    int[] next = add(player, direction);

    switch (room[next[Y]][next[X]]) {
        case BOX_ON_GOAL:
        case BOX:
            int[] behind = add(next, direction);
            if (!(room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] == FREE || room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] == GOAL)) {
                return false;
            }

            if (room[next[Y]][next[X]] == BOX_ON_GOAL) {
                emptyGoal++;
                freeBox++;
            }

            if (room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] == GOAL) {
                room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] = BOX_ON_GOAL;
                emptyGoal--;
                freeBox--;
            } else {
                room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] = BOX;
            }

            if (room[next[Y]][next[X]] == BOX_ON_GOAL) {
                room[next[Y]][next[X]] = GOAL;
            } else {
                room[next[Y]][next[X]] = FREE;
            }
        case GOAL:
        case FREE:
            if (room[player[Y]][player[X]] == PLAYER_ON_GOAL) {
                room[player[Y]][player[X]] = GOAL;
            } else {
                room[player[Y]][player[X]] = FREE;
            }

            player = next;

            if (room[player[Y]][player[X]] == FREE) {
                room[player[Y]][player[X]] = PLAYER;
            } else {
                room[player[Y]][player[X]] = PLAYER_ON_GOAL;
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    if (!loadLevel(file)) {
        System.err.println("Level has an invalid format");
        return;
    }
    if (game()) {
        System.out.println("Yeah you have solved the level :)");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have not solved the level :(");
    }
    printLevel();
    System.out.println("Goodbye");

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length > 0) {
        file = args[0];

    }
    launch(args);
}
}
```

**EDIT: Run Output**

> ant -f C:\Users\Nouri\Desktop\Sokobangame jfxsa-run
>       init:
>       Deleting: C:\Users\Nouri\Desktop\Sokobangame\build\built-jar.properties
>       deps-jar:
>       Updating property file: C:\Users\Nouri\Desktop\Sokobangame\build\built-jar.properties
>       compile:
>       Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
>       jfx-deployment:
>       jar:
>       Copying 12 files to C:\Users\Nouri\Desktop\Sokobangame\dist\run822624664
>       jfx-project-run:
>       Executing C:\Users\Nouri\Desktop\Sokobangame\dist\run822624664\Sokobangame.jar
>   using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre/bin/java
>       Exception happened while loading 'Sokoban.txt'
>       Level has an invalid format

EDIT 2:

```
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception happened while loading 'Sokoban.txt'");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Run Output:

> C:\Users\Nouri>cd C:\Users\Nouri\Desktop\Sokobangame\dist
>
> C:\Users\Nouri\Desktop\Sokobangame\dist>java -jar Sokobangame.jar
>   Exception happened while loading 'Sokoban.txt'
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: sokoban.txt
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Unknown Source)
>           at sokobangame.Sokobangame.loadLevel(Sokobangame.java:52)
>           at sokobangame.Sokobangame.start(Sokobangame.java:243)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Level has an invalid format

Comment: What's the exception message/stacktrace?

Comment: If you want to know why an exception is thrown, then ignoring it is the best way to miss your goal. Print its stack trace. It will tell you what and where is the problem.

Comment: See EDIT: Run Output

Comment: See EDIT 2: stacktrace

Comment: If you are running from a .jar file, you cannot use a `Path`; you need to read the data with [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).  If you are not running from a .jar file, you need to familiarize yourself with current directories and relative file names, which are fundamental concepts in computing.

Answer (score 0):

Well the NoSuchFileException exception you are getting is pretty self explanatory as to what the problem is.

You use a hardcoded path for the file you want to load via doing this:

```
public static String file = "sokoban.txt";
```

In your main though, you try to get the file from the command line arguments. Either leave the variable unitialized and do it this way, or initialize your path variable with the correct content.

Also a couple of other hints. You open up a BufferedReader, which you close at the end of your operation. Closing the read should better be moved in a finally block. This is a good idea to ensure that your resource will close even if an exception happens. Ideally and since you use java.nio.files.* you could use try-with-resources statements to auto-close them in order to ensure that your resource are always closed.

Comment: I use a hardcoded path which I overwrite with an Argument in case `args.length > 0 == true`. My idea isn´t wrong I guess ... check my answer. The problem was that I just wrote the file name without path (not the whole path) as the hardcoded path.